# switch input is not working properly in Shiny dashboard

Tags: shiny

I am having trouble with using a switch input to switch between maps in Shiny dashboard. I am using `radioGroupButtons` as my switch input. However this does not seem to work properly as it only shows the first map once (see gif below).

[myMap1 output is only showing once](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/KnobbyHoarseHedgehog-small.gif)

I have attempted to use other switch inputs like `checkboxInput` and   `checkboxGroupButtons` but the result remains the same.

**Reproducible code**

```
library(recharts); library(echarts4r); library(echarts4r.maps)
library(shiny); library(shinyWidgets); library(shinydashboard)
library(purrr)

data_by_region <- data.frame(
  Name = rep("A", 8),
  Region = rep("Northland", 8),
  long = rep(174.3223, 8),
  lat = rep(-35.7047, 8),
  Year = 2013:2020,
  Amount = c(227, 252, 373, 363, 287, 307, 308, 293)
)

# Remove Chatham Island for echarts4r maps
nz_file <- system.file("New_Zealand.json", package = "echarts4r.maps") 
nz_json <- jsonlite::read_json(nz_file)

# get names of polygons
names <- nz_json$features %>% 
  map("properties") %>% 
  map("name") %>% 
  unlist()

island_index <- grep("Chatham", names)

nz_json$features[[island_index]] <- NULL


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
   selectInput(inputId = "year", 
                label = "pick a year",
                choices = unique(factor(data_by_region$Year))),
    radioGroupButtons(
      inputId = "switchMap", label = NULL, justified = TRUE,
      choiceNames = c("Map", "Advanced"),
      choiceValues = c("Map1", "Map2"),
      status = "primary"
    ),
    fluidRow(column(6, uiOutput(outputId = "map")))
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
   output$map <- renderUI({
     if(input$switchMap == "Map1"){
       echarts4rOutput(outputId = "myMap1")
     }else{
       eChartOutput(outputId = "myMap2")
     }
    })
   
    output$myMap1 <- renderEcharts4r({
      data_by_year <- data_by_region[data_by_region$Year == req(input$year),]
      data_by_year <- data.frame(data_by_year)
      data_by_year$Region <- factor(data_by_year$Region)
      
      data_by_year %>%
        e_charts(Region) %>%
        e_map_register("NZ", nz_json) %>%
        e_map(Amount, map = "NZ") %>%
        e_visual_map(
          Amount,
          top = "20%",
          left = "0%",
          inRange = list(color = c("#3366FF","#6699FF", "#66CCFF", "#33CCFF")),
          type = "piecewise",
          splitList = list(
            list(min = 300),
            list(min = 250, max = 300),
            list(min = 100, max = 250),
            list(value = 0, label = "None")
          ))
    })
    
    output$myMap2 <- renderEChart({
      yeardata <- data_by_region[data_by_region$Year == input$year, ]

      top5dat <- as.data.frame(yeardata) %>% top_n(5)

      top5dat <- data.frame(top5dat)

      names(top5dat) <- c('Family', 'name', 'lng', 'lat', 'Year', 'value')

      echartr(NULL, type='map_world', subtype = 'New Zealand') %>%
        addMP(series = 'Top 5',
              data = top5dat,
              symbol = 'pin',
              symbolSize = JS('function (v) {return 10 + v/50;}'),
              effect = list(show = TRUE),
              itemStyle = list(normal = itemStyle(color = "#EE82EE"))
        ) %>%
        addGeoCoord(top5dat[, c('name', 'lng', 'lat')]) %>%
        setToolbox(show = FALSE) %>%
        setSeries(hoverable = FALSE, itemStyle=list(
          normal = itemStyle(
            labelStyle = labelStyle(color="#EE82EE"),
            borderColor = 'rgba(100,149,237,1)', borderWidth = 0.5,
            areaStyle = areaStyle(color='#1b1b1b')))) %>%
        setLegend(show = FALSE) %>%
        setTitle('Advanced map', 'Fictious Data', pos = 11)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need `req(input$switchMap)` in the first line of `output$map`. Sorry, cannot verify as I am unable to install some of the required packages.  You should change your `output$map` as given below:

```
output$map <- renderUI({
  req(input$switchMap)
  if(input$switchMap == "Map1"){
    echarts4rOutput(outputId = "myMap1")
  }else if (input$switchMap == "Map2"){
    eChartOutput(outputId = "myMap2")
  }else {return(NULL)}
})
```

Similar issue has been resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045963/how-to-hide-or-display-charts-in-shiny-dashboardbody-based-on-radiogroupbutton-s/63063758#63063758).

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I tried putting ```req(input$switchMap)``` before ```   output$map <- renderUI({...})``` like you said but it still didn't work. Thanks for your help anyway I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MinhChau, It should be `output$map <- renderUI({ req(input$switchMap)…})`

Comment: Sorry I was meant to say  ```output$map <- renderUI({ req(input$switchMap) ....})``` but messed up my words. But yeah unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to reply but I have tried it your way but it still doesn't work. I have switched from ```eChartOutput``` to ```echarts4rOutput``` for **myMap2** output and it works fine! Thank you for your help!!